# SAAS based mobile application

Tags: asp.net, saas

We are developing SAAS based mobile application in asp.net.

In our business domain we have different companies and all flows under those. Each company has a different URL, when super admin will create the company on front end and then parse the url to load each company specific logos and other settings.

We are confused about url management for different companies. How should we handle different sub domain urls hitting same physical location? and please share any other guidelines that we must follow to develop SaaS based web site.

Answer (score 5):

Identifying the tenants by URL is the standard in developing SaaS Applications.

It is pretty easy and straight forward too. From my experience, I suggest you the following

1. Configure the IIS site to use root level domain (i.e. yourawesomeapp.com). This makes all the subdomain request hit the same site.
2. Store your tenants URL like tenant1.yourawesomeapp.com, tenant2.yourawesomeapp.com, etc., in your tenant table
3. Tell your tenant to use that url to access the application
4. Write a HttpModule, in PostAuthenticateRequest Event grab current request URL and verify it with the TenantURLMapping entries (cache the url <-> tenant mapping in a Dictionary at application start to improve performance)

   - If request domain is not in TenantURLMapping; deny the access
   - If the request is authenticated, verify the authenticated Tenant url/id is sames as the current one, else deny access (tenant url/id can be stored in cookie in encrypted format when logon)
   - Load the required settings and store them in HttpContext.Items to use in the later part of the request.

Answer (score 3):

What you are about to develop is called **multi tenant** application. The correct term for this will let you google tons of information.

When it comes to url management, there are two approaches:

- separate subdomain for each tenant (client), like

  http://client1.your.application.com

  http://client2.your.application.com
- the same domain but separate url segment, like

  http://your.application.com/client1

  http://your.application.com/client2

From the technical perspective, both approches are straightforward.

In the former case there is one caveat however - each time you add a new tenant, you have to bind the new header to the existing iis site. This requires automating iis, either manually or automatically but still, in iis multiple headers can be bound to the same site. Getting a tenant name for current request is just reading the value of `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`.

In the latter case, creating a new instance could be as easy as creating a new entry in the [tenant -> connectionstring] mapping. Getting a tenant name for current request involves some kind of url mapping facade - if the website is developed with MVC or WebAPI, you just add an additional segment to the routing entry.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor :) We want to go with first approach, Can you please share a comprehensive tutorial that we can follow?

Comment: @saira: Google for "ASP.NET multi tenant" to find tons of information.